# How to random reward with rate

Tags: javascript

how to random by rate, I got 0.1% random, but still got reward 1 What should I do to get it completely random?

```
var Reward = [
    {
        "Text": "Reward 1",
        "Rate": 60
    },
    {
        "Text": "Reward 2",
        "Rate": 0.5
    },
    {
        "Text": "Reward 3",
        "Rate": 0.1
    },
];

for (i = 0; i < Reward.length; i++) {
    var result = ((Math.random() * (100 - 0)) + 0).toFixed(2);
    if (result <= Reward[i].Rate) {
        console.log(Reward[i].Text);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: change the order of your Reward list. with your example, `0.1%` is always `<=` than `60%` so there will be no other answer.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const Reward = [
    {
        "Text": "Reward 1",
        "Rate": 60
    },
    {
        "Text": "Reward 2",
        "Rate": 0.5
    },
    {
        "Text": "Reward 3",
        "Rate": 0.1
    },
]

const numProps = Object.keys(Reward).length
const ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(numProps))
console.log(`Random number was ${ranNum + 1}, ${Reward[ranNum].Text} with a rate of ${Reward[ranNum].Rate}%`)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're searching for a number that is `<=` than the number stored on list, and the list is decreasing it's values.

So you need to change the order that the values are stored in the list, or the order that you search through that list.

See the following snippet with the list inverted and the tests for each reward:

```js
var Reward = [
    {
        "Text": "Reward 3",
        "Rate": 0.1
    },
    {
        "Text": "Reward 2",
        "Rate": 0.5
    },
    {
        "Text": "Reward 1",
        "Rate": 60
    },
    
];

for (i = 0; i < Reward.length; i++) {
    var result = 0.1;
    if (result <= Reward[i].Rate) {
        console.log(Reward[i].Text);
        break;
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < Reward.length; i++) {
    var result = 0.3;
    if (result <= Reward[i].Rate) {
        console.log(Reward[i].Text);
        break;
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < Reward.length; i++) {
    var result = 48;
    if (result <= Reward[i].Rate) {
        console.log(Reward[i].Text);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want *a single random element from the `Reward`s array*:

```
var result = Reward[Math.floor(Math.random() * Reward.length];
```

That can be abstracted, so there you go:

```
var randomEntry = items => items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];

randomEntry(Reward);
```

Working example:

```js
const Reward = [
    {
        "Text": "Reward 1",
        "Rate": 60
    },
    {
        "Text": "Reward 2",
        "Rate": 0.5
    },
    {
        "Text": "Reward 3",
        "Rate": 0.1
    },
]

const randomEntry = items => items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];

const item = randomEntry(Reward);
console.log(`Got reward with text ${item.Text} and rate ${item.Rate}`);
```

---

**Notes**

*Complexity*

This line:

```
var result = ((Math.random() * (100 - 0)) + 0).toFixed(2);
```

is overly complex and can safely be reduced to:

```
var result = (Math.random() * 100).toFixed(2);
```

However, not that `.toFixed` returns a `String`, not a `Number`! This means you compare numbers with strings in your `if` statement, which will *almost always* yield falsy results (read: not what you expect). Better drop the call to `.toFixed` and compare `Number`s with `Number`s. This will simplify the line *again*:

```
var result = Math.random() * 100;
```

*Recalculating `result`*

With each iteration, the `result` variable is recreated/assigned a new value. I expect that you want to calculate it *only once* instead of *for every item in `Reward`*. If I'm right, move the line above the `for` loop.